# Show that a polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I need to show that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ and in $\mathbb{F}_{29}[x]$.

I know that I can start by finding the roots of the polynomial, but I'm not sure how to follow.

Comment: The zeros of $x^2+x+1$ are the non-trivial cube roots of $1$. Are there any such cube roots in your fields?

Comment: If a quadratic is reducible it factors into linears.  How many monic linear polynomials are there with coefficients in $\Bbb{F}_5$?  Would it take very long to check whether each of them divides the given polynomial (perhaps by writing $(x-a)(x-b) = x^2+x+1$ and solving the coefficient equations mod $5$)?  How about $\Bbb{F}_{29}$?  Even if you just make a table of $(a,b)$ pairs, the requirement $a b \cong 1$ makes a much smaller table.

Comment: Using Lord Shark's hint is surely the simplest way. It implies that this polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_p$ whenever $p\equiv2\pmod3$. Do you see why? Anyway, I'm sure we have covered the question in that form many times on our site in various guises.

Answer (score 4):

We can show that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in both $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ and $\mathbb{F}_{29}[x]$ with a few observations.

**Observation 1:** Let $K$ be a field and let $f(x)\in K[x]$. If the degree of $f(x)$ is $2$ or $3$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible iff $f(x)$ has no roots.

**Observation 2:** $(x^2+x+1)(x-1)=x^3-1$. So if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$, then $\alpha$ is also a root of $x^3-1$. Hence $\alpha^3=1$. If the characteristic of the field is not $3$, then $1$ is not a root of $x^2+x+1$, so the roots of $x^2+x+1$ are elements $\alpha$ with $\alpha^3=1$ and $\alpha\ne1$.

**Observation 3:** Let $K=\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$. Then $K^{\times}=K-\{0\}$ is a group under multiplication. An element $\alpha\in K$ with $\alpha^3=1$ and $\alpha\ne1$ would be element of order $3$ in $K^{\times}$. Note that the order of $K^{\times}$ is $p-1$. Hence if $K^{\times}$ has elements of order $3$, then $3$ divides $p-1$.

**Comment:** In fact, if $K$ is a field of order $p$, then $K^{\times}$ is cyclic. So $K^{\times}$ will have elements of order $3$ iff $3$ divides $p-1$, but we won't need this to show that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ and $\mathbb{F}_{29}[x]$.

**Conclusion:** Since the order of $\mathbb{F}_5$ is $5$ and the order of $\mathbb{F}_{29}$ is $29$, and both $5,29\equiv2$ (mod $3$), it follows that $\mathbb{F}_5^{\times}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{29}^{\times}$ don't have elements of order $3$. So $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in both $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ and $\mathbb{F}_{29}[x]$.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbf F_5[x]$, you can easily check there's not root, writing the elements of $\mathbf F_5$ as $0, \pm 1,\pm 2$ to speed up a bit the computations.

As to $\mathbf F_{29}[x]$, simply compute the discriminant:
$\Delta=-3$, and use the law of quadratic reciprocity:
$$ \biggl(\frac{-3}{29}\biggr)= \biggl(\frac{-1}{29}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{3}{29}\biggr)=
\bigl(-1\bigr)^{\tfrac{28}2}\biggl(\frac{29}{3}\biggr)\bigl(-1\bigr)^{\tfrac{28}2\cdot\tfrac22}=\biggl(\frac{29}{3}\biggr)=\biggl(\frac{2}{3}\biggr)=-1, $$
so $\Delta$ has no root in $\mathbf F_{29}$, and the polynomial has no root in this field.